# How do you pass a session state through a Redirect in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form in MVC that does validation through the form's ActionResult.  If Validation fails, I want to reload the page. So, what I'm doing is this:

```
bool ValidationErrors = true;
if (ValidationErrors != false)
{
    return Redirect("~/Admin/EditPage");
}
```

But, I want the page to retain what has been put into the form.  It will load the page, but it will reload the form from the data.  I don't want to make the user reenter all their changes.  Better yet, isn't there just a way to refresh the dang browser???

Comment: Typically, you just return the view, and the view model (which you'd have passed into the post action)

Comment: Your if-condition can look like if (ValidationErrors) { ... }, no need to do != false.

Comment: And add the validation errors to `ModelState` so that they are displayed in the view

Comment: If my page is Admin/EditPage and my post action is Admin/SubmitEdit, then return View() just returns Admin/SubmitEdit, which takes me to a 404.

Comment: Why would you give them different names (normal convention would be to have a GET and POST method named `Edit()`? But you can specify the view name in `return View("EditPage", model);`

Comment: The problem here is that some of the control properties on the page are set in the controller function that loads the view.  So, using this method, that logic never runs, and it causes the page to not behave appropriately.  I don't know why the page is designed like this... I didn't build it.  I just can't believe there isn't a way to say, "Reload the page with the current state."

Comment: There is - as per my last comment its `return View("EditPage", model);` and if you need to reset some logic, then add that same logic in the post method before you return the view.

Comment: What I'm saying is, when I do that, it skips the ActionResult that actually loads the view.  There are objects that need to be assigned in that method.  all View("EditPage", model) does is bring up that view, but it doesn't rerun the ActionResult that loads the objects.  There are drop-downs on that page whose choices are determined on the fly.  If the loading ActionResult isn't running, the view throws null exceptions.

Comment: You need to reload the collections use for your dropdowns in the POST method before you return the view (just as you would have done in the GET method)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86839/discussion-between-hill-and-stephen-muecke).